# GCP Blockchain Node Engine API Quota Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, json-rpc, go-ethereum

I have deployed an ETH Full node using GCP's Blockchain Node Engine. Having an issue with the APIs to access the JSON-RPC endpoint. So in the limits and quotas page they have mentioned two kinds of request limits
https://cloud.google.com/blockchain-node-engine/docs/quotas:

1. Blockchain node API per minute per project  : 38400
2. Control plane API per minute per project     : 240

I am using APIs mentioned at this URL:
https://cloud.google.com/blockchain-node-engine/docs/using-nodes-ethereum

And for some reason, only hitting Control Plane API quota.

My question is how do I use Blockchain node API quota?

Answer (score 0):

Yasir, this was a temporary issue that has been resolved. If you have any other issues, please reach out.